# Check if declared global temporary table exists in current session

Tags: java, sql, db2, temp-tables

How can I check if a declared global temporary table in DB2 exists or not in the current session?

I need to create the temporary table once for a user session and then be able to insert rows in it each time a report is executed in the case of my application. So I need to delete all the rows from this table when a report is executed for more than the first time and then re-populate it with new rows.

Right now the method creating the temporary table is throwing a `42710 SQLSTATE error` the second time it is executed.

Does this statement work for my implementation: `DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '42710' SET DGTT_FOUND=1` and how can I use it in Java (`executeUpdate()` ?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your DB2 version, which you conveniently not indicated, you can use the `WITH REPLACE` option when declaring the temporary table, which will not only succeed even though the table has been previously declared, but will also take care of deleting the previously inserted rows.

```
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE mytab (
  ...
) NOT LOGGED WITH REPLACE
```

Comment: This will work for DB2 LUW and DB2 for i, but not for those using DB2 z/OS.  DB2 z/OS does not support WITH REPLACE, at least as of v10, but it may be supported in a future release.

Answer (score 0):

Because declared temporary tables are not defined in the catalog, and they are only visible in your current session (each session could have a different definition of the same temporary table name), you could only try to query the table and analyze the answer.

First, try a

```
select count(0) from session.myTempTable
```

If DB2 says it does not exists, then you can define a new table.

If DB2 says it DOES exist, you can create it or drop it, in order to recreate it. I think this is your case, because you got a SQL State 42710, then you can create a handler for you code.

However, handlers can be used in SQL procedures, so you should create a SP, to be called before your query. That SP will check if the table exists, and you will put what you want to do when it exists and when it does not.

References:

Handles - http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/c0009025.html

Tables - http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/r0054491.html