# Check if QTemp table exists in Db2

Tags: sql, db2

Is there a Db2 function that allows me to check if a table already exists?

I have a stored procedure that executes a command to create a table, however I only want to call it if the table doesn't exist.

I can't query the catalogs because files in Qtemp don't show in there.

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if declared global temporary table exists in current session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17464902/check-if-declared-global-temporary-table-exists-in-current-session)

Answer (score 2):

You can query `SYSIBM.SYSTABLES` to have information about tables.

For your case:

```
SELECT count(1)
FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES
WHERE NAME = 'tableName' AND TYPE = 'T'
```

You can also check views and temprary tables by changing `TYPE`.

[SYSIBM.SYSTABLES docs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/cattab/src/tpc/db2z_sysibmsystablestable.html)